# How can I preset a filename for saving a html page?

Tags: html

I have a webpage like e.g. `www.example.com/NYSE/rates`. If the user decides to save the html she sees on her local disk, I want to preset the filename she gets, when she clicks "Save as", with `NYSE_rates_09_12_2011.html`. (Which obviously will be different tomorrow or for a different stock exchange.) Now I always get `rates.html` as default.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out, this is a [known problem](http://daggle.com/getting-firefox-to-save-with-page-title-as-filename-6) with Firefox, that stems from the days of Netscape Navigator. And there is an [add-on "File Title"](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/file-title/?id=834) that fixes it.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that in at least the latest version of the most popular web browsers on Windows (Internet Explorer, Firefox, Chrome, Safari and Opera) the default filename filled in when saving a webpage is taken from the page's `<title>` tag, so simply making sure the date appears in there should put you right.

Comment: You are right, I tested this in Chrome and Safari, and there the filename is made out of the title-tag. But in Firefox (which is my main browser) it's made out of the last part of the URL. So the question boils down to how Firefox is made to behave in the desired way.